# Flutter Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_peerConnection@24207864' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I want to make a video call in Flutter that gives this error, please help me

Thanks

[image]

For using webrtc, unfortunately I can't find any source, if there is a website for guidance on using webrtc, please share it with me.

Comment: you can use [this](https://flutter-webrtc.org/docs/docs/)

Comment: Please provide code and error message in text form and not as an image only